# Ligação SIP - Softphone Java Android

Tags: java, android, voip, sip

Minha intenção é criar um Softphone, para isto estou consultando as bibliotecas do google e fazendo alguns testes só que empaquei em uma parte.

Não quero fazer funções de início, nem várias telas, nem nada complicado. Só quero realizar uma ligação.

Criei as instâncias como o google diz e etc. Segue abaixo meu código.

**MainActivity.java**

```java
package br.com.coligarse.testevoip;

import android.net.sip.SipException;
import android.net.sip.SipManager;
import android.net.sip.SipProfile;
import android.net.sip.SipRegistrationListener;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.ParseException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView status;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SipManager mSipManager = null;

        if (mSipManager == null) {
            mSipManager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
        }
        SipProfile mSipProfile = null;


        SipProfile.Builder builder = null;
        try {
            builder = new SipProfile.Builder("100", "voip.servidor.net.br:5082");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        builder.setPassword("123456");
        mSipProfile = builder.build();

        try {
            mSipManager.setRegistrationListener(mSipProfile.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {

                public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                    updateStatus("Registering with SIP Server...");
                }

                public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                    updateStatus("Ready");
                }

                public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                                                 String errorMessage) {
                    updateStatus("Registration failed.  Please check settings.");
                }

            });
        } catch (SipException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void updateStatus(String msg){
        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
        status.setText(msg);
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.coligarse.testevoip">
    <receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver" android:label="Call Receiver"/>
    ...
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    ...
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="br.com.coligarse.testevoip.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Quando executo este código. Ele abre o app em branco e na sequência ele diz que parou de funcionar e fecha.

Alguém poderia me informar onde estou errando ou de dar uma orientação em como continuar?

Realmente tenho dúvidas de como proceder. Já li vários documentos, mas sou iniciante e não estou achando um romo certo. Minha intenção é desenvolver tudo no android studio pelo SDK sem utilizar plugins externos ou o NDK.

**LOGCAT**

```
 --------- beginning of crash
 09-12 13:06:47.543 2416-2416/br.com.coligarse.testevoip E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: br.com.coligarse.testevoip, PID: 2416
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.coligarse.testevoip/br.com.coligarse.testevoip.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.net.sip.SipManager.setRegistrationListener(java.lang.String, android.net.sip.SipRegistrationListener)' on a null object reference
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.net.sip.SipManager.setRegistrationListener(java.lang.String, android.net.sip.SipRegistrationListener)' on a null object reference
 at br.com.coligarse.testevoip.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Consegue postar o log do erro ??

Comment: logcat postado , da uma conferida por gentileza

Comment: Verifica se o `mSipProfile` ou o  `mSipManager` não está null quando você chama `setRegistrationListener`

Answer (score 1):

O logcat diz:

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.net.sip.SipManager.setRegistrationListener(java.lang.String, android.net.sip.SipRegistrationListener)' on a null object reference
> ```

Ou seja, o `mSipManager` era `null`.

Veja a [documentação do método `SipManager.newInstance(Context)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html#newInstance(android.content.Context)):

> ## newInstance
>
> `SipManager newInstance (Context context)`
>
> Creates a manager instance. Returns null if SIP API is not supported.
>
> Parameters
>
> `context`    Context: application context for creating the manager object
>
> Returns
>
> `SipManager`    the manager instance or null if SIP API is not supported

Traduzindo para o português:

> ## newInstance
>
> `SipManager newInstance (Context context)`
>
> Cria uma instância do *manager*. Retorna null se a API SIP não for suportada.
>
> Parâmetros
>
> `context`    Context: contexto da aplicação para a criação do objeto manager
>
> Retorna
>
> `SipManager`    a instância do manager ou null se a API SIP não for suportada

Ou seja, o método `newInstance(Context)` pode retornar `null`. Você não trata isso no seu código. Veja:

```
    SipManager mSipManager = null;

    // SEMPRE vai entrar.
    if (mSipManager == null) {
        // Pode retornar null.
        mSipManager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
    }

    // ...

    try {
        // Se o newInstance retornou null, vai dar NullPointerException.
        mSipManager.setRegistrationListener(/* ... */);
```

Ou seja, se o `SipManager.newInstance(Context)` retornar `null`, o seu `mSipManager.setRegistrationListener` vai dar um `NullPointerException`.

A solução para isso é primeiramente, verificar se o `SipManager.newInstance(Context)` retorna `null`, e se for esse o caso tratar isso adequadamente.

Em segundo lugar, acho que você deveria usar o [`InCallService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService.html) ao invés do `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: agora o meu oncreate que deu problema eu mudei o manifest mas o oncreate da main nao ta rolando

Comment: @JasarOrion Você está usando isso em um celular de verdade com chip habilitado ou está usando no android studio?

Comment: celular d verdade com chip habilitado ( LG g3 )

Comment: @JasarOrion Bem, então não sei. Espero que a minha resposta tenha ao menos te ajudado um pouco. Boa sorte aí, e se achar a solução, não se esqueça de postá-la aqui para compartilhar o conhecimento com todos.

Comment: sim estou fuçando no google agora para descobrir pq meu on create da main parou de funcionar quando tirei o AppCompactActivity

Comment: è , não consegui fazer funcionar ;(